# react-table setFilter with custom filter function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I am trying to set a filter on a column using `react-table` . I'd like a checkbox change to filter multiple possible values for one column.

Let's say I have a table like this. When the checkbox is checked - I want all instance to show. When not checked I want everything but instance checked.

[image]

```
const columns = useMemo( () => [
  {
   Header: 'col1',
  accessor: 'col1'
  },
 {
   Header: 'col2',
  accessor: 'col2'
  } 
 {
   Header: 'col3',
  accessor: 'col3'
  } 
], [] )

const {
...
setFilter,
filters,
} = useTable(
  {columns, data},
  useFilters
  ....
)



const onFilterChange= (e, value) => {
   if(e.target.checked){
     setFilter('col3', 'instance') //works!
   }
   else{
     setFilter('col3', cell => cell.value !== 'instance' ) //does not work - how do I do this?
   }
   

}


return (
<input
  type="checkbox"
  onChange={ e => onFilterChange(e, 'instance')}
  />

)
```

Can I pass a custom function into `setFilter` ? Not seeing how to do this with `react-table`

Comment: You might find this [discussion](https://github.com/TanStack/react-table/discussions/2247) helpful.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful - in the column definitions you can define a function to call when you run `setFilter` - that's what I was able to use.

Comment: Yes I'll try to post the solution soon

Comment: @Ryan, posting the solution would be very helpful who have a similar question :)

Comment: @Ryan Did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the argument is the old filter value, not cell

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).